# for loop repeating same size row in shopping cart page?

Tags: php, mysql, database, loops, for-loop

i have a shoppingcart page where for loop count session cart but problem is that i'm retrieving `sizes` values from mySQL database now `for loop repeating single row` again and again with every products now i want to display different `sizes` for every products? please help me thanks in advance?

**Select Size Query From MySql Table**

```
function get_size($id){
$result=mysql_query("SELECT mywishlist.`sizes`
FROM mywishlist ORDER BY id DESC ") 
or die("Id Problem"."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
return $row['sizes'].'<br>';
}
}
```

**Shopping Cart For Loop Condition**

```
<?php
if(is_array($_SESSION['cart'])){

$max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
$id=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['id'];
$q=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty'];
$product=get_product_name($id);
$image=get_product_image($id);
$ids=get_id($id);
$itemcode=get_itemcode($id);
$size=get_size($id);
if($q==0) continue;
?>

<div style="margin-left: -20px;"> <?php echo $sizes; ?> </div>
<input type="hidden" name="size[]" value="<?php echo $sizes; ?>" /></td>
<?php } } ?>
```

**Even I have tried with the help of Session But Still Same Problem**

```
$sizes=$_SESSION['sizes1'];
```

**My MySQL Table Picture I have Two DIfferent Sizes**

[image]

**SHopping Cart Page **
[image]

Comment: you missed `where` condition in `get_size`

Comment: I noticed that your `get_size($id)` function isn't passing the `$id` into the mysql query.

Comment: so friends what is solution for this problem?

Comment: when i echo size out of for loop condition then display all rows?

Answer (score 0):

when you do a return the loop exits

try:

```
function get_size($id){
$sizes = array();
$result=mysql_query("SELECT mywishlist.`sizes`
FROM mywishlist ORDER BY id DESC ") 
or die("Id Problem"."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
$sizes[] =  $row['sizes'];
}
return implode('<br>', $sizes);
}
```

i think i spotted the error still use the code i provided above

and make the following change in your shopping cart for loop condition

```
 $sizes=get_size($id); // instead of $size=get_size($id);
```